# My Neural network is perfroming regression instead of classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am working on a Data Science project which requires implementation of a neural network. The dataset I am providing for training is not sequential and has class labels. But I don't know why it is treating it as sequence of events.

I am using the following code for the model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.4),
    layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.4),
    layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.4),
    layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=2100)
y_pred=model.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

The `accuracy_score` function is giving this error

```
Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets
```

This error messages shows when the algorithm is performing the regression. How can I solve this issue?

**Edit 1**

As suggested by Michael Hodel I have applied the `OneHotEncoder` instead of using `LabelEncoder`.

```
data['label']= ohc.fit_transform(data[['label']])
```

It is giving me error

```
sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

**Edit 2**

I used `pd.get_dummies()` instead of 'OneHotEncoder`

Comment: I am pretty sure that this error complains about your **targets** not your predictions. Check what is inside `y_test`

Comment: It might be worth double-checking that all your classification labels are integers.

Comment: Yes I use 'LabelEncoder' for preprocessing and double checked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `y_pred` are floats, but `accuracy_score` expects integers. I'd recommend you one-hot encode your labels and use the `categorical_crossentropy` loss function. Then `y_pred` represent the class probabilities which can simply converted to predictions via `y_pred.argmax(axis=1)`. An example with mock data:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import numpy as np

n_classes = 6
n_variables = 100
n_examples = 1000
X = np.random.normal(0, 1, (n_examples, n_variables))
y_ = np.random.choice(n_classes, size=n_examples)
y = np.eye(n_classes)[y_]

idx = int(n_examples * 0.8)
X_train, y_train = X[:idx], y[:idx]
X_test, y_test = X[idx:], y[idx:]

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.4),
    layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.4),
    layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.4),
    layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=10,batch_size=100)
y_pred=model.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test.argmax(axis=1), y_pred.argmax(axis=1)))
```

Here `y_` are your classes of shape `(n_examples,)`, and `y` are the one-hot encoded classes of shape `(n_examples, n_classes)` and `model.predict(X_test)` gives predicted probabilities of shape `(n_examples, n_classes)` and `model.predict(X_test).argmax(axis=1)` gives prediced classes of shape `(n_examples,)`.

Comment: I have used LabelEncoder and made sure that my `y_test` are integers 1 to 6

Comment: What do your classes represent? If there is no inherent order in them (agreeing with the numbering), then the LabelEncoder is probably not an adequate choice.

Comment: I have updated the question. There is an error I am getting with `OneHotEncoder`